# value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['whatever']); ?>" not working in select tag

Tags: php, html

my code is written below

```
 <select name="year"  required  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']); ?>"  >
               <option>----SELECT----</option>
    <option value="1">1<sup>st</sup></option>
    <option value="2">2<sup>nd</sup></option>
    <option value="3">3<sup>rd</sup></option>
    <option value="4">4<sup>th</sup></option>
  </select>
```

htmlspecialchars() is not working for select tag.is there any mistake or there is some other    way to do it

Comment: What does it mean `is not working`?

Comment: You didn't closed your select tag...

Comment: i am not getting the value which i have selected before the submition

Comment: Are you trying to have one of your `<option>`s selected?  Adding a `value` attribute to the `<select>` is not how you do that.  You really need to explain your problem better than "is not working", but what you need to do is add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the correct `<option>` tag.

Comment: What's going on with your option tag for third? You've mixed up your sup tags and there's a random closing bold tag... Do you know what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set the default value of a select you have to set the option that contains this value as selected like this:

```
<select name="year" required="required">
    <option>----SELECT----</option>
    <option <?php if((int)($_POST['year'])==1){?>selected<?php } ?> value="1">1<sup>st</sup></option>
    <option <?php if((int)($_POST['year'])==2){?>selected<?php } ?> value="2">2<sup>nd</sup></option>
    <option <?php if((int)($_POST['year'])==3){?>selected<?php } ?> value="3">3</sup>rd<sup></b></option>
    <option <?php if((int)($_POST['year'])==4){?>selected<?php } ?> value="4">4<sup>rth</sup></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I usually like to use `<?=($_POST['year']==1)?'selected':''?>`.

Comment: it is very much satisfactory but required="required" is not working now ?

Comment: @vivekpuri updated my code, just add `required` after `name="year"` deleted it by mistake

Comment: @vivekpuri Safari and ie 8/9 do not support this attribute

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Yes!  Definitely, use the ternary operator and alternate syntax to lose the ugly curly braces.

Comment: @vivekpuri ah now I understand, well if you an option already selected, there is no reason for the required works. required only works when the value (currently selected option) of the select is empty

Comment: but when i am trying to login again and not selecting any option then also it is not showing the massage that it is necessary to select atleast one of the option?

Comment: and also if i want to compare to a string then instead of int i have written string. Is it correct? if so then why the code <?php if((string)($_POST['branch'])=='cse'){?>selected<?php } ?> not working? thanks alot for the response.

Comment: no it haven't solved my problem even now its not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign a `value` attribute to a `select` tag; you assign it to `option` tags.  It's not clear what you are trying to do, but `<select ... value="...">` is just invalid HTML.  [**See the specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6).

Answer (score 0):

you cannnot give value in `<select>` tag. Value is given in `<option>` tag.

like

```
<select name="year">
    <option>----SELECT----</option>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']); ?>">
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']); ?></option>

    <option value="1">1<sup>st</sup></option>
    <option value="2">2<sup>nd</sup></option>
    <option value="3">3</sup>rd<sup></b></option>
    <option value="4">4<sup>rth</sup></option>
 </select>
```